# Alter HTTP Header, Ruby, Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, web-scraping, http-headers, watir

I have a server running on debian.  It runs a scraper using ruby and watir which loads up in a headless fashion.  I notice that a site can read the HTTP header my browser passes.  How can I hide the HTTP info, or give false info, so a site cannot see my computer operating system?

Comment: what you're talking about is the USER_AGENT header, though there may be other ways to fingerprint clients . See [how to avoid fingerprinting in browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/how-to-fight-browser-fingerprinting).

Comment: i dont see a change the USER_AGENT on a headless browser (such as i have on my server)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution.  I used x11 forwarding to access chrome from my local computer which has a user interface.  It is possible to change the User Agent via dev tools -> network conditions, but this does NOT persist on new sessions.  So I installed the first result on google for "plugin change chrome user-agent" and this does the trick.